# DeepDiff exclude_paths regex not filtering out paths

Tags: python, deep-diff

I have two dictionaries I'd like to compare using DeepDiff, excluding the `"a"` key in the `"items"` list:

```
d1 = {"items": [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": 2}]}
d2 = {"items": [{"a": 10, "b": 2}, {"a": 100, "b": 2}]}

exclude_paths = [r"root\['items'\]\[\d+\]\['a'\]"]
diff = DeepDiff(d1, d2, exclude_paths=exclude_paths)
pprint(diff)
```

Ideally DeepDiff should report an empty dictionary but it's reporting the `"a"` values.

```
{'values_changed': {"root['items'][0]['a']": {'new_value': 10, 'old_value': 1},
                    "root['items'][1]['a']": {'new_value': 100,
                                              'old_value': 1}}}
```

Am I doing anything wrong in my `exlude_paths` regex? I'm following the [docs](https://zepworks.com/deepdiff/current/exclude_paths.html).

I've tried others values for `exlude_paths` but no luck:

```
r"root['items'][\d+]['a']"
r"root\[\'items\'\]\[\d\]\[\'a\'\]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to use the `exclude_regex_paths` argument instead of the `exclude_paths` argument:

```
d1 = {"items": [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": 2}]}
d2 = {"items": [{"a": 10, "b": 2}, {"a": 100, "b": 2}]}

diff = DeepDiff(d1, d2, exclude_regex_paths=[r"root\['items'\]\[\d+\]\['a'\]"])
pprint(diff)  # {}
```